# Split the data in the specific column in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I start to study python and I have one question in the data frame!
In the df, let's say CarName columns.

```
CarName
chevrolet impala
chevrolet monte carlo
dodge rampage
```

In the CarName column's data is consist of car-brand and car-model
I want to make new columns so I applied split function to separate.

```
CarBrand = df['CarName'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

But when I tried to get car-model with this code

```
CarModel = df['CarName'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1])
```

The result shows list index out of range error

What will be an efficient way to split the data properly?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
                 CarName
0       chevrolet impala
1  chevrolet monte carlo
2          dodge rampage

In [32]: df.CarName.str.split(" ",1,expand=True).rename({0:"CarBrand",1:"CarModel"},axis=1)
Out[32]:
    CarBrand     CarModel
0  chevrolet       impala
1  chevrolet  monte carlo
2      dodge      rampage
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `index=1` to apply the function to each row.

```
CarBrand = df['CarName'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0], index=1)
CarModel = df['CarName'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1], index=1)
```